# Что именно выводит response в conslole.log()?

Tags: javascript, php, форма, axios

возник вопрос касательно javascipt,через него я отправляю данные на сервер, а потом смотрю в консоли, что возвращает сервер в объекте response, я заметил, что в консоли также есть часть кода, который написан в php-файле, который как раз таки принимает данные. 
Я правильно понял, что при отправке запроса с js в php-файле по мимо приема данных, выполняется код написанный в этом php-файле , и потом результат отправляется через объект response?

То что выводится в консоли(обведенная data - это результат выполнения кода в php-файле, для чего но нужен?):[image: скриншот]

Comment: код php:

$data=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);


if(isset($data)){
  echo ('filled data');
}else{
  echo ('empty data');
}

echo '<br>';
var_dump($data);

Comment: Весьма странный вопрос. Вы используете xhr, но, судя по вопросу, вы не знаете что такое xhr... Тогда зачем вы его используете?

Comment: В дате естественно в таком формате var_dump();

Comment: мне нужен был способ отправки данных на сервер, и я не вдавался в подробности отправки данных.
Тогда начну изучать xhr

Comment: можете изучить fetch, очень просто